# How can I sum a range as defined by me?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a named range from A1 to C6 with 3 columns in it for ID (A1), Cost (B1), and Units (C1).

I want to have cells E1 and E2 define the range in which column 2 of this range, "transactions", is summed; but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT() to do this.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(E1):INDIRECT(E2))
```

This formula will sum the range specified by cells E1 and E2.  Those cells should contain cell references, such as "B2" and "B6" (without quotes).  That will give the sum of rows 2 to 6 in column B.

The INDIRECT() function converts a text string into a cell or range reference.
[Here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) is some further information about INDIRECT(), and this website is also a valuable general resource for Excel tips and techniques.